# SQL SERVER 2017 Query Optimizer gives a million of estimated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have SQL Server 2017 and we've just changed our compatibylity mode to 140. We expected to improve performance but unlike so many queries take a long time and consume many server resources. The reason seems to be that the new query optimizer estimates millions of rows when the actual rows are 2.

For instance, with a little query the QO estimates 1500 rows
[execution plan with bad estimate](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyYuzm7-8),
 though if with OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9481) the estimate is perfectly acurate 
[execution plan with acurate estimate](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyCZBmXZU)

I don't know if it is a parameter sniffing case because, if we change the value of one of the filters, the query is correct. But with the degree of compatibility 110 the 2 queries are executed correctly.

[execution plan with other parameter](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJBXEQXWU)

We have the statistics perfectly updated.
Would anyone know what I should do to solve this problem?

EDITED**
Statistics are updated every day with the Ola Hallengren's algorithm, where SQL Server automatically computes the required sample. However, since we are doing tests with this query, we have done several fullscan.
Database statistics options are:
Auto Create Incremental Statistics False
Auto Create Statistic True
Auto Update Statistic True
Auto Update Statistic Asynchronously False
Legacy Cardinality Estimation OFF
Parameter Sniffing ON
Query Optimizer Fixes OFF

I've just tried OPTION (RECOMPILE) and the QO estimates 2300 rows

You can see the actual query in the execution plan's links but, is something like this:

```
SELECT  
        table1.field1  
FROM table1  
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2.field1 AND table2.date_field=(  
      SELECT MAX( date_field ) 
      FROM table2 as t2  
      WHERE table2.field1 = t2.field1  
             AND t2.date_field<=@date 
)  
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.field1 = table3.field1 AND table3.date_field=(  
      SELECT MAX( date_field ) 
      FROM table3 as t3  
      WHERE table3.field1 = t3.field1  
             AND t3.date_field<=@date 
)
```

field1 is key in table1 and field1 and date_field are key in table2 and table3. 
This kind of queries are very comon in our system with no problems until the upgrade compatibylity mode.

The data in these tables may change once a day. The original query is really much more complicated, estimating 300 million rows and with the previous level it had no problem. To investigate what happened, I started from the most basic levels of the query.
The tables have at most 85,000 records and the density is 3 or 4 records per key. at most, in some cases it reaches 6.
The steps followed to change the server configuration are:

1. New EC2 instance in amazon with SQL Server 2017 Standard Edition
2. We create our databases with compatibilty level 110 and restore the data of our SQL Server 2012
3. 2 weeks later we modified the compatibility level 140.
4. 2 weeks later we enable Query Store

Comment: `We have the statistics perfectly updated.` ← Elaborate. How are your statistics maintained? Be detailed. What type of sampling do you do or do you run full scans? How often does the data change? How frequently do you update the statistics? What type of database statistics options are enabled / disabled? Have you tried running the query using OPTION (RECOMPILE)?  Have you tried running the query using parameter hints?  Are there values in the data that could return 1500 rows? What does the query itself look like (proper join syntax etc).

Comment: Yes, *exact details,* of *everything* that you did to change the server configuration, will be needed to properly diagnose this problem.

Comment: SQL Server started to use a new Cardinality Estimator (CE) since SQL 2014 (120). The new CE can cause some queries slow down. You may have to force to use the legacy CE using trace 9481

Comment: Yes, we are solving the problem temporarily with OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9481), but our intention was to move forward

Comment: Yes, I put links where you can see the diferentes plans with/without OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9481).

Comment: Relevant Documentation: [Joe Sack’s white paper about the new Cardinality Estimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn673537(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)